# How to retrieve data from dataextension using fuelsdk java

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, dataextensions, fuel-sdk

I am trying to retrieve records currently contained in a data extension. I have checked the documentation but couldn't typically find out how to retrieve from the extension and examples I've found online are pretty old as the sdk has been updated. What I have currently is that it retrieves all of my data extension but I only want to retrieve one of my data extension. The name of the data extension I want to retrieve is "Customer_opt". I also have the external key of the Customer_opt data extension.

This is what I have so far:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ETSdkException {
    SpringApplication.run(SoapApplication.class, args);

    ETConfiguration configuration = new ETConfiguration();
    configuration.set("clientId", clientId);
    configuration.set("clientSecret", clientSecret);
    ETClient client = new ETClient(configuration);

    ETSoapConnection soapConnection = new ETSoapConnection(client, "https://@@@@@@@@@@.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx");


    ETResponse<ETDataExtension> response = client.retrieve(ETDataExtension.class);
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

EDIT = This is what I have and now able to query the data extension:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ETSdkException {
    SpringApplication.run(SoapApplication.class, args);

    ETConfiguration configuration = new ETConfiguration();
    configuration.set("clientId", clientId);
    configuration.set("clientSecret", clientSecret);
    ETClient client = new ETClient(configuration);

    ETSoapConnection soapConnection = new ETSoapConnection(client, "https://@@@@@@@@.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx");
    ETFilter etf = new ETFilter();
    ETExpression expression = new ETExpression();
    expression.setProperty("name");
    expression.setOperator("=");
    expression.setValue("Customer_opt");
    etf.setExpression(expression);

    ETResponse<ETDataExtension> response = client.retrieve(ETDataExtension.class, etf);

    System.out.println(response);
}
```

BUT I've noticed that the fields do not come with the response. I've checked it with another data extension that I have and I cant seem to find the fields.

This is what the `response` outputs:

```
com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETResponse[
batchResult = com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETResult[
    status = OK
    requestId = XXXXXXXX
    responseCode = OK
    responseMessage = OK
]
individualResults = [com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETResult[
    object = com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETDataExtension[
        id = XXXXXX
        key = XXXXXX
        name = Customer_opt
        description = 
        createdDate = Fri Dec 07 06:10:07 GMT 2018
        modifiedDate = Wed Apr 24 23:47:42 BST 2019
        folderId = XXXXX
        columns = []
        isSendable = false
        isTestable = false
    ]
]]
moreResults = false
```

]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what it is inside the SDK, but I believe you are looking at the wrong Object. 
'[DataExtension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextension.htm)' is essentially all the properties and structure of the DE - not the data contained in it.

For that you would need to use the '[DataExtensionObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextensionobject.htm)' Object, which represents the rowsets inside of a specific Data Extension.

A good resource for retrieving data from a data extension is the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm). It is not SDK specific, but through this and the SDK documentation you should be able to correctly sync it up.

Sample of SOAP Envelope for DataExtensionObject:

```
 <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
 <RetrieveRequest>
 <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[Example DE]</ObjectType>
 <Properties>EMAIL_ADDRESS</Properties>
 <Properties>CUSTOMER_ID</Properties>
 <Properties>FIRST_NAME</Properties>
 <Properties>SITE_GROUP</Properties>
 <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
 <Property>EMAIL_ADDRESS</Property>
 <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
 <Value>acruz@example.com</Value>
 </Filter>
 </RetrieveRequest>
 </RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

Which will return:

```
  <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
    <RequestID>a484cd16-5cf8-4eb7-b4a1-ea2fba75f6fc</RequestID>
    <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
      <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
      <Type>DataExtensionObject</Type>
      <Properties>
       <Property>
         <Name>EMAIL_ADDRESS</Name>
         <Value>acruz@example.com</Value>
       </Property>
       <Property>
         <Name>CUSTOMER_ID</Name>
         <Value>11111</Value>
       </Property>
       <Property>
         <Name>FIRST_NAME</Name>
         <Value>A</Value>
       </Property>
       <Property>
         <Name>SITE_GROUP</Name>
         <Value>22222</Value>
       </Property>
      </Properties>
    </Results>      
   </RetrieveResponseMsg>
```

Comment: Managed to get it working. Turns out what I had was correct but needed to use the `select()` method on the ETDataExtension object to get the results.